# can I Mix t force vulcan z and delta ram?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, computer-building

I have T force Vulcan Z RAM 8GB 3200mhz  I couldn't find the same RAM... So I bought T force Delta RGB 16GB 3200mhz but I'm worried that they might don't work together

Comment: They are the same frequency. Why wouldn’t they be compatible with one another? They meet the specifications of the DDR generation they are.